# Nexus 5 won't start stuck on loading screen

Tags: nexus-5, boot, images

My Nexus 5 has been stuck on the loading screen. After turning it off it wouldn't start and after showing the "Google" logo would just spin the 4 coloured dots for hours on end.

I tried a few things such as clearing the cache and doing a factory reset through the bootloader, but this didn't work.

I did some research and came across [this forum topic](http://androidforums.com/threads/nexus-4-stuck-in-boot-animation.883416/) which suggested re-installing an image. It took me a long time to figure out how to do this, but I eventually followed [this guide](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images)

It involved unlocking the bootloader, for which I got the warning that my warranty would be voided, but I thought whatever I need to try this.

I followed all the steps and installed this "5.1.0 (LMY47I)" with the checksum "d78c50bc06fe37a19536cbca0a17394a" from [the Google website here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images)

When I was in recovery mode LMY47I was listed at the top, so I presume that this is the correct image to use.

This seemed to be installed just fine. However when the phone restarted I was still left with the same problem. The four dots just spin endlessly and the phone does not start.

Is there anything else I can do to resolve this?

UPDATE: I managed to get the phone to start by using the image "4.4 (KRT16M)", the earliest listed for the Nexus 5.

After doing this I was able to start the phone but camera, gallery and play store kept coming up with an "unexpectedly stopped" error.

I decided to go through the stages of upgrading bit by bit before installing any apps or doing anything else. I was using the system update in settings, not the bootloader. This seemed to be going okay (although strangely no signal) until I got to either 5.1 or 5.0.1 (I can't remember which) and after the download, install and reboot I was back with the spinning dots loading screen indefinitely again.

Comment: Any reason you're not using [Nexus Root Toolkit by WugFresh](http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/)?

Comment: I've not heard of it and it seemed safer to use Google's official stuff.